# Why do I get reports of my Nginx redirect failing?

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

I've got a website sitting behind an Nginx proxy. I've set up Nginx to redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, like so:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

  location /api {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass api-server:80;
  }

  location / {
    root /web;
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should work. And when I hit my server from multiple locations using curl, I see the permanent redirect I was expecting. But I'm getting reports from some users that they're not getting redirected; instead they're seeing a generic **Welcome to nginx!** page.

Is there a better configuration I should be using? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate log files for the http and the https server and see if there are other status code than 301 in the one from the http server.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/